# Появление текста на jQuery

Tags: jquery

[image: схема]

Есть блок, в который добавляются элементы. Когда ни одного не добавлено - выводится надпись о том, что ничего нет (1 экран). Потом добавляются элементы, каждый из которых можно удалять, они не зависят друг от друга (2 экран). Когда все элементы удалены, снова выводится надпись. Вопрос в том, как реализовать появление надписи после удаления всех добавленных блоков?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function addToContainer() {
  $(".container").prepend("<div class='something'>Something is here</div>");
}
function removeFromContainer() {
  $(".container .something").eq(0).remove();
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.container *~.nothing {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="nothing">Nothing is here</div>
</div>
<br/>
<button onclick="addToContainer()">Add</button>
<button onclick="removeFromContainer()">Remove</button>
```